# <div> won't display in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

First and third div are displayed, but the second won't display at any cost, even with CSS disabled.

```
<%= provide(:title, 'Ask a question')%>

<div id="ask">
  <h1>Ask a Question</h1>

  <% if logged_in? %>
    <%= render 'question_form' %>
  <% else %>
   <p>Please login to ask/or answer questions</p>

  <% end %>
</div><!-- end ask -- >


<div>
  <h2>Unsolved Questions</h2>
  <p>why this does not work</p>
  <% if @questions.any? %>
  <ul><% render @questions %></ul>
    <%= will_paginate %>
  <% else %>
     <p>No questions have been asked.</p>
  <% end %>
</div><!-- end questions-->

<div><p>test test</p></div>
```

Comment: `<!-- end ask -- >` close the comment properly, to `<!-- end ask -->`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!-- end ask -- >
```

This HTML comment here isn't terminated properly. It should be:

```
<!-- end ask -->
```

If you check the syntax highlighting of your question, it should become apparent.

Comment: well vim did not show me anything wrong. Now I just deleted them both, and it worked. But when I've put them back including the same spacing they worked as well. So why is that???